# How to delete $1,000 from a column that has "ABCDE $1,000 $1,00,000" in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column in SQL table that has value "ABCDE $1,000 $1,00,000". I have to delete $1,000 and expected result is "ABCDE $1,00,000". How do I achieve this? This is an example. However, there can be data with different numbers and I need to identify the greater number or the lesser number from such column values and delete them.

SQL Server and Have tried below functions just to extract the numbers:

```sql
DECLARE @string varchar(100),

 @start int,

 @end int,

 @len int

SET @string = 'ABCDE $1,000 $1,000,000'
set @string = replace(@string, ' ' , '')

set @len = len(@string)

set @start =  PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@string)

set @end =  PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',substring(@string, @start, @len))-1

print substring(@string, @start, @end)
```

---

```sql
declare
@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256) = 'ABCDE $1,000 $1,000,000'

BEGIN  
DECLARE @intAlpha INT  
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)  
select @intAlpha
BEGIN  
WHILE @intAlpha > 0  
BEGIN  
SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' ) 
--select @strAlphaNumeric  
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )  
--select @intAlpha
END  
END  
select @strAlphaNumeric
END  
GO
```

Have also tried below function to see if I can change to function to achieve this:

```sql
DECLARE @instr   varchar(max)
SET @instr = 'ABCDE $1,000 $1,000,000'
    DECLARE @workstr  varchar(max) = REPLACE(LTRIM(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
              LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(LTRIM(@instr), ' ', '_'))), CHAR(9), ' '), CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(11), ' '), CHAR(12), ' '), CHAR(13), ' ')))), ' ', '_'),
    @tokenque VARCHAR(MAX),
    @newstr   INT = 0,
    @token varchar(max),
    @flag_break INT = 0
    print @workstr
-- removes the extra "spaces"
    WHILE CHARINDEX('__', @workstr) <> 0
        BEGIN
        SET @workstr = REPLACE(@workstr, '__' , '_')
        END
    SET @tokenque = @workstr
    WHILE (CHARINDEX('_', @tokenque) <> 0)
    BEGIN
    SET @token = SUBSTRING(@tokenque, 1, CHARINDEX('_', @Tokenque) - 1 )
    IF @token <> '''' -- (') delimiter skipped
      BEGIN
      WHILE CHARINDEX(@token + '_' +  @token, @workstr) <> 0
        BEGIN
        SET @workstr = REPLACE(@workstr, @token + '_' + @token, @token)
        END
      SET @tokenque = SUBSTRING(@tokenque, LEN(@token) + 2, LEN(@tokenque) )
       END
    ELSE SET @tokenque = SUBSTRING(@tokenque, LEN(@token) + 2, LEN(@tokenque) )

    --PRINT @tokenque --if you want to see the progression  
    END
PRINT REPLACE(@workstr, '_', ' ')
```

Comment: what you have tried so far

Comment: and what DBMS are you using?

Comment: In SQL, each row should have one value per column. You are doing it wrong.

Comment: `"ABCDE $1,000 $1,00,000"` is *one* column of type text, right? As @Tobb already remarked, this is not the "SQL-way" of doing things ...

Comment: @cars10m - I agree, but the data available is in this format. Its an existing data that we are trying to clean up.

Comment: That's not even the format of the text in your own supplied answer. You should be supplying the actual format of the example data in the question and not nonsense formatted data.  In the future put example data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SQL should do it, using a sample string @s. It splits the string on spaces, then selects the first amount, and finally aggregates the row back again, prefixing with your required prefix string.

You can modify the SELECT TOP(1) to SELECT MAX([value]) to get the highest number, or MIN for the lowest, as you need.

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(1000) = 'ABCDE $1,000 $1,000 $500 $750 $500 $1,000'

SELECT STRING_AGG([value], ' ')
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP(1) value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@s,' ')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [value]
    FROM (SELECT TOP(1) value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@s,' ') WHERE value LIKE '$%') AS i
) AS j
```

Output is:

"ABCDE $1,000"

EDIT:

*If you need to sort by numeric amount, edit as below. Order column r by DESC for MAX and ASC for MIN value:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(1000) = 'ABCDE $1,000 $1,000 $500 $750 $500 $1,000'

SELECT STRING_AGG([value], ' ')
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP(1) [value] FROM STRING_SPLIT(@s,' ')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [value]
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (CONVERT(NUMERIC, REPLACE(REPLACE(value, '$', ''), ',', ''))) DESC) AS r
         , value
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@s,' ') 
        WHERE value LIKE '$%'
    ) AS i WHERE i.r=1
) AS j
```

Output is:

"ABCDE $1,000"

Edited the CONVERT, to also handle decimals.

Edit2: Added this to give you control over MAX/MIN:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(1000) = 'first $1,000.00 $1,000.50 $500 $750 $500 $1,000'

SELECT STRING_AGG([value], ' ')
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP(1) [value] FROM STRING_SPLIT(@s,' ')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [value]
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (CONVERT(NUMERIC, REPLACE(REPLACE(value, '$', ''), ',', ''))) ASC) AS a
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (CONVERT(NUMERIC, REPLACE(REPLACE(value, '$', ''), ',', ''))) DESC) AS d
         , value
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@s,' ') 
        WHERE value LIKE '$%'
    ) AS i WHERE (@s LIKE 'first%' AND i.d=1) OR (@s LIKE 'second%' AND i.a=1)
) AS j
```

Comment: Will try and get back to you

Comment: If the MIN/MAX is not what you need, then we need a description of the sort order (what does $1,00,000 mean, is there a missing zero perhaps?)

Comment: I added alternate sorting

Comment: this works perfectly. However, for decimal the conversion fails. I'm working on this to tackle more scenarios. Will submit the final query and the results soon

Comment: I'm posting my script as answer. Please check the same. I have covered whatever scenarios I have seen in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of working with these composite columns made up of text and numbers is really *horrible*, but if you are dumped with this awful task then maybe the following could be useful for you:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getmax(@txt nvarchar(1000)) returns nvarchar(max)
BEGIN
DECLARE @ret nvarchar(max);
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT Split.b.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') da
  FROM ( SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@txt, ' ', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String ) AS a
  CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(b)
), t2 AS (
  SELECT (SELECT MAX(da) n FROM t1) nam, da, REPLACE(REPLACE(da,'$',''),',','')-0 val
  FROM t1 WHERE LEFT(da,1)='$')
SELECT TOP 1 @ret=nam+' '+da FROM t2 ORDER BY val desc;
RETURN @ret
END
```

I use the SQL-Servers's XML capabilities to split the column into its individual parts (first a text part and then any number of $-amounts). I then clean up the $-amounts by taking away any `$` signs and blanks and order it (descending) by their numeric value. After that I take the first record and combine the text part with the original $-value string and return it after first storing it in the variable `@ret`.

On my SQL server I was then confronted with an error message telling me, that I needed to use the setting `SET ARITHABORT ON;`, after which it worked, but so far I have *not* managed to get it working on a whole table. For some reason the function returns the first record only.

Comment: Will try this and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Grab a copy of [PatternSplitCM](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/splitting-strings-based-on-patterns) and this is easy as blueberry pie.

**Solving for a single value:**

```
DECLARE @string       VARCHAR(1000) = '"ABCDE $1,000 $1,00,000"'
DECLARE @searchString VARCHAR(1000) = '$1,000';

SELECT NewString = 
(
SELECT   CASE f.Item WHEN @searchString THEN '' ELSE f.Item END
FROM     dbo.PatternSplitCM(@string,'%[0-9,$]%') AS f
ORDER BY f.itemNumber
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(8000)');
```

**Returns:**

```
NewString
-----------------------
"ABCDE  $1,00,000"
```

**Against a table:**

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @sometable TABLE (SomeID INT IDENTITY, SomeString VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT @sometable (SomeString) VALUES ('Blah, blah... $1,000... Joe said "1,000"'),
('$1,000 Blah, blah... $1,001... $100, $50... 1,0000000'),('Yada Yada... ');

DECLARE @searchString VARCHAR(1000) = '$1,000';

SELECT * 
FROM   @sometable AS t
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT NewString = 
    (
    SELECT   CASE f.Item WHEN @searchString THEN '' ELSE f.Item END
    FROM     dbo.PatternSplitCM(t.SomeString,'%[0-9,$]%') AS f
    ORDER BY f.itemNumber
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
    ).value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(8000)')
) AS f;
```

**Returns:**

```
SomeID   SomeString                                               NewString
-------- -------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------
1        Blah, blah... $1,000... Joe said "1,000"                 Blah, blah... ... Joe said "1,000"
2        $1,000 Blah, blah... $1,001... $100, $50... 1,0000000    Blah, blah... $1,001... $100, $50... 1,0000000
3        Yada Yada...                                             Yada Yada...
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple replace would work I think

```
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(100)

SET @STRING = 'ABCDE $1,000 $1,00,000'

SELECT REPLACE(@STRING, '$1,000', '')
```

result: ABCDE  $1,00,000

Comment: "However, there can be data with different numbers and I need to identify the greater number or the lesser number from such column values and delete them."  That one wouldn't identify the lesser value to delete.  And the value is not necessarily '$1,000', is it merely the lesser of the two.

Answer (score -1):

@SAS Below is what I have created and this has covered the scenarios whichever I have seen so far. Thank you so much for your help. I might have created a long query just to tackle the scenarios. But will simplify it and post it when done. Only issue i'm finding with the output is that "Second Value is: Per day 1,000,000.23" should come in the next line. Have tried with char() but seems to be not working:

```sql
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(1000) = 'First value is: Per day 10 1,000
Second Value is: Per day 1,000,000.23 $1,000.01'

select value into #temp  from string_split(@s,CHAR(10))

declare @s1 VARCHAR(1000) = (select value from #temp where value like 'first%')
declare @s2 VARCHAR(1000) = (select value from #temp where value like 'second%')

drop table #temp

declare @s3 varchar(1000) = (SELECT STRING_AGG([value], ' ')
FROM
(
    SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@s1,' ') WHERE value not LIKE '%[0-9]%%[.][0-9]%' and value not like '%[0-9]%'  and value not LIKE '$%'
    UNION ALL
        SELECT [value]
    FROM (
        --SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (CONVERT(int, REPLACE(REPLACE(replace(value, '$', ''), ',', ''),CHAR(10),''))) asc) AS r
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (CONVERT(decimal, REPLACE(LTRIM(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
              LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(LTRIM(value), '$', ''))), CHAR(9), ''), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(11), ''), CHAR(12), ''), CHAR(13), '')))), ',', ''))) asc) AS r
         , value
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@s1,' ') 
        WHERE value LIKE '%[.][0-9]%' or value LIKE '%[0-9]%'  or value LIKE '$%'
    ) AS i WHERE i.r=1
) AS j)


declare @s4 varchar(1000) = (SELECT STRING_AGG([value], ' ')
FROM
(
    SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@s2,' ') WHERE value not LIKE '%[0-9]%%[.][0-9]%' and value not like '%[0-9]%'  and value not LIKE '$%'
    UNION ALL
        SELECT [value]
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (CONVERT(decimal, REPLACE(LTRIM(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
              LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(LTRIM(value), '$', ''))), CHAR(9), ''), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(11), ''), CHAR(12), ''), CHAR(13), '')))), ',', ''))) desc) AS r
         , value
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@s2,' ') 
        WHERE value LIKE '%[.][0-9]%' or value LIKE '%[0-9]%'  or value LIKE '$%'
    ) AS i WHERE i.r=1
) AS j)

declare @s5 varchar(1000)=(select (@s3+CHAR(13)+@s4))
select @s5


OutPut: First value is: Per day 10 Second Value is: Per day 1,000,000.23
```

Comment: OK, good that it helped you! 
Remember to upvote and accept the answers that helped you. :)

Comment: Actually, I think you could combine the two main SELECTs into one, with just a new sort-column. That would simplify the code. I added to my answer.

Comment: Also, reganding the second row, since, it shows in SSMS if you display the output as text (not grid), so the linebreak is there as you want it.